# Recursive adding file to folder and create folder if it doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, recursion, windows-installer, directory

I'm trying to add a config file recursively to following path: C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\

Heres my code so far:

```
#Sets config file as source.
$Source = "$dirFiles\NewAgentAP\AgentAP.cfg"

#Recursive copying of a file to specific folder destination.
$Destination = 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Trio\Trio Enterprise'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}
```

I would want the powershell script to add the path for each user if they don't have it already and afterwards add the .cfg file.  I have tried searching about the problem but without luck.

Comment: Change your single quotations to doubles and see if that helps. With your current code, Powershell assumes the folder name is * and not using it as a wildcard.

Comment: Didn't change the outcome. Tried `'C:\Users\*\'` as a path which seems to work fine. Problem seems to be that some users have a AppData folder while other users doesn't and therefore the script can't proceed. If I feed it a path that already exists, it works like a charm. Thanks tho.

Comment: Is this done from a custom action in an MSI package? Or is it run via Active Directory or some other mechanism? If this is a package, does it install an application with its own EXE that gets launched, or is it a plugin install hooking up to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good solution here would be to iterate all user folders, make sure the destination path exists, and then perform your copy.

```
#Sets config file as source.
$Source = "$dirFiles\NewAgentAP\AgentAP.cfg"

#Recursive copying of a file to specific folder destination.
$Destination = 'AppData\Roaming\Trio\Trio Enterprise'
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\* -Directory | ForEach-Object {New-Item -Path (Join-Path $_.FullName $Destination) -ItemType "directory" -Force | Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}
```

Using `New-Item` to create the folder, and the `-Force` switch will cause it to create the folder if it doesn't exist, and pass on the folder object, or if it does exist it just passes on the folder object without doing anything else.

Comment: This approach is interesting! Almost there. Right now it creates a file called "Trio Enterprise" at `C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Trio\` instead of creating `C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Trio\Trio Enterprise\AgentAP.cfg`
Tried Adding an additional backslash at the end of $Destination, but didn't work.

Comment: Instead of `New-Item -Force` I'd use `New-Item -ItemType "directory"` The alias MD seems to imply this.

Comment: Updated to include the item type, thanks for the suggestion.